# Category term for “global” and “local”

Tags: single-word-requests, programming, hypernyms

What is a term for the category of global and local in programming? For example I want to use local/global in my game, but I need a word that means global or local. The word be used like so:

> The ____ is global.

**For programmers**

I'm trying to make an enumeration that uses Global and Local, except I need a word to categorize the enum.

**Edit:**
To clarify why the answer is definitely scope: 
I am making a high score system and I would like there to be the local high score and the global high score.

Comment: Do you mean "scope"?

Comment: I think thats it!

Comment: Turn that into an answer and I'll give it to you

Comment: I would say "[declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_(computer_programming))", as you declare to the code that variable is either a local variable or a global variable.

Comment: Its scope because I'm specifically trying to figure out whether it is local or global.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In programming, [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) is the term used to describe the parts of the  program where a binding of a name to an entity - e.g. a variable - is valid.

Comment: Cant believe I forgot that -_-

Comment: Scope is the word in almost every context, not just programming

Answer (score 2):

**range** defines the area or sphere in which an activity takes place.

> - the limits within which any fluctuation takes place.
> - the limits within which a thing can function effectively  -  [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/range)

Comment: Note that this is a question specifically about programming lexicon, and `range` means something completely different to `scope`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an answer, but as another option:

**Domain**

- *the local domain*
- *the global domain*

Or

- *the domain is local*
- *the domain is global*

Comment: This may be true too. I'll think about this one.

Comment: In my vocabulary, *scope* is the *property*, and it can take on *values* from the *domain* of {global,local}.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this depends heavily on the blank in your question.

In the problem domain you are modelling in your program, what exactly is it that has the property *global* or *local*? If it's variables, then it's **scope**. But if it's influence of characters (maybe you're building an RPG) **reach** or **range** etc. might be better words...

It's analogous to asking what's a good enum name for the values *1meters* and *2meters* — it depends on whether you're modelling the height of characters or radius of pillars.

Answer (score 0):

"Binding" is another word often used in computer science, which means the same as " scope ".

Example: Variable " X " is locally bound.